# Debugging with Emulator is not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-debugging, android-studio-debugger

I tried debugging with the emulator in Android Studio several times. It initially worked well for the first four runs, but then it failed to connect to the emulator for debugging. I didn't change any debugging configuration code.

I've already tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, as well as invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio. I've also read nearly all the posts here about debugging with an emulator and tried the suggested solutions, but none of them resolved the issue. What could be causing this problem?
I'm getting this system/out message in Logcat

```
2023-11-23 14:56:46.753  8659-8659  System.out              com.example.androidapp               I  Waiting for debugger first packet
2023-11-23 14:56:50.194  8659-8659  System.out              com.example.androidapp               I  Debug.suspendAllAndSentVmStart
2023-11-23 14:56:52.098  8659-8659  System.out              com.example.androidapp               I  Debug.suspendAllAndSendVmStart, resumed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N51Y.jpg)
```